# Existence of the limit of a function

Tags: limits

I have a the following doubt. Consider a function $$f(w): \frac{1}{\frac{w^2}{(2-w)^2}+1}(2-w)$$ with $w \in [0,2]$. We can compute

$$
\lim_{w \rightarrow 2}f(w)=\frac{1}{\frac{4}{0}+1}(2-2)=\frac{1}{\infty}*0=0*0=0
$$

Question: computing the limit in the way I have done above requires assuming that $\lim_{w \rightarrow 2}f(w)$ exists or is a way of showing that $\lim_{w \rightarrow 2}f(w)$ exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are considering a limiting process like this, you should never write $\lim_{w \to 2} f(w) = f(2)$ unless you already know the function is continuous there. Also, generally, you should not write things like $4/0$ or treat infinity as a real number.

To work around this, we can rewrite $f$ as
$$ f(w) = \frac{(2-w)^3}{w^2 + (2-w)^2}. $$

Then, since the numerator goes to $0$ and the denominator goes to $4$ as $w \to 2$ (as polynomials are continuous), a basic result tells us that $\lim_{w \to 2}f(w)$ exists and is equal to $$\frac{\lim_{w \to 2}(2-w)^3}{\lim_{w \to 2} w^2 + (2-w)^2} = \frac{0}{4} = 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Just some algebra should do the trick. If you receive an indeterminant form like $\frac{0}{0}$, use algebra to work it out so that it actually works. If you still receive an indeterminant form, then the limit does not exist there.

$$\lim_{x\to2}\frac{1}{\frac{w^2}{(2-w)^2}+1}(2-w)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to2}\frac{1}{\frac{w^2}{(2-w)^2}+\frac{(2-w)^2}{(2-w)^2}}(2-w)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to2}\frac{1}{\frac{w^2+(2-w)^2}{(2-w)^2}}(2-w)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to2}\frac{(2-w)^2}{w^2+(2-w)^2}(2-w)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to2}\frac{(2-w)^3}{w^2+(2-w)^2}=$$
$$\frac{(2-2)^2}{2^2+(2-2)^2}=$$
$$\frac{0}{4+0}=\frac{0}{4}=\boxed{0}$$

Comment: fixed. @BarryCipra